# Flyway V 7.8.1 doesn't migrate the first script that it creates H2 table

Tags: java, h2, flyway

Flyway V 7.8.1 identifies that PUBLIC schema is updated the first time that H2 database is created, and it doesn't execute the first sql script that it create the sample table.

The log execution is:

```
[INFO] Running example.credentials.flyway.entities.Test1Flyway
13:39:09:593 (main) DEBUG [i.q.f.r.QuarkusPathLocationScanner] Locations: [classpath:db/migration-test]
13:39:09:596 (main) DEBUG [i.q.f.r.QuarkusPathLocationScanner] Loading db/migration-test/V1.0.0__INITIAL_STRUCTURE_OF_TABLES_WITH_SOME_DATA
13:39:09:603 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.s.c.ClassPathScanner] Scanning for classpath resources at 'classpath:db/callback' ...
13:39:09:604 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.s.c.ClassPathScanner] Determining location urls for classpath:db/callback using ClassLoader QuarkusClassLoader:Quarkus Base Runtime ClassLoader ...
13:39:09:604 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.s.c.ClassPathScanner] Unable to resolve location classpath:db/callback.
13:39:09:609 (main) INFO  [o.f.c.i.l.VersionPrinter] Flyway Community Edition 7.8.1 by Redgate
13:39:09:730 (agroal-11) DEBUG [e.c.f.s.c.CipherManager] Shared key File: shared.key
13:39:09:731 (agroal-11) DEBUG [e.c.f.s.c.CipherManager] Shared key Type File: resource
13:39:09:731 (agroal-11) DEBUG [e.c.f.s.c.CipherManager] LaunchMode (current): TEST
13:39:09:750 (agroal-11) DEBUG [e.c.f.s.MyBbddCredentialsProvider] my-bbdd-credentials-provider/username:tools
13:39:09:750 (agroal-11) DEBUG [e.c.f.s.MyBbddCredentialsProvider] my-bbdd-credentials-provider/password:********
13:39:10:238 (main) INFO  [o.f.c.i.d.b.DatabaseType] Database: jdbc:h2:./target/db/example (H2 1.4)
13:39:10:238 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.d.b.DatabaseType] Driver  : H2 JDBC Driver 1.4.200 (2019-10-14)
13:39:10:328 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.Flyway] DDL Transactions Supported: false
13:39:10:328 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.Flyway] Schemas: public
13:39:10:328 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.Flyway] Default schema: null
13:39:10:333 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.c.SqlScriptCallbackFactory] Scanning for SQL callbacks ...
13:39:10:334 (main) DEBUG [i.q.f.r.FlywayRecorder] Filtering out resource: db/migration-test/V1.0.0__INITIAL_STRUCTURE_OF_TABLES_WITH_SOME_DATA (filename: V1.0.0__INITIAL_STRUCTURE_OF_TABLES_WITH_SOME_DATA)
13:39:10:363 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.c.DbClean] Dropping pre-schema database level objects...
13:39:10:365 (main) INFO  [o.f.c.i.c.DbClean] Successfully dropped pre-schema database level objects (execution time 00:00.001s)
13:39:10:366 (main) WARN  [o.f.c.i.c.DbClean] Unable to clean unknown schema: "public"
13:39:10:366 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.c.DbClean] Dropping post-schema database level objects...
13:39:10:367 (main) INFO  [o.f.c.i.c.DbClean] Successfully dropped post-schema database level objects (execution time 00:00.000s)
13:39:10:367 (agroal-11) DEBUG [e.c.f.s.c.CipherManager] Shared key File: shared.key
13:39:10:368 (agroal-11) DEBUG [e.c.f.s.c.CipherManager] Shared key Type File: resource
13:39:10:368 (agroal-11) DEBUG [e.c.f.s.c.CipherManager] LaunchMode (current): TEST
13:39:10:370 (agroal-11) DEBUG [e.c.f.s.MyBbddCredentialsProvider] my-bbdd-credentials-provider/username:tools
13:39:10:371 (agroal-11) DEBUG [e.c.f.s.MyBbddCredentialsProvider] my-bbdd-credentials-provider/password:********
13:39:10:373 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.Flyway] Memory usage: 122 of 305M
13:39:10:374 (main) INFO  [o.f.c.i.l.VersionPrinter] Flyway Community Edition 7.8.1 by Redgate
13:39:10:376 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.Flyway] DDL Transactions Supported: false
13:39:10:377 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.Flyway] Schemas: public
13:39:10:377 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.Flyway] Default schema: null
13:39:10:379 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.c.SqlScriptCallbackFactory] Scanning for SQL callbacks ...
13:39:10:379 (main) DEBUG [i.q.f.r.FlywayRecorder] Filtering out resource: db/migration-test/V1.0.0__INITIAL_STRUCTURE_OF_TABLES_WITH_SOME_DATA (filename: V1.0.0__INITIAL_STRUCTURE_OF_TABLES_WITH_SOME_DATA)
13:39:10:390 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.c.DbSchemas] Creating schema: "public"
13:39:10:390 (main) INFO  [o.f.c.i.d.b.Schema] Creating schema "public" ...
13:39:10:400 (main) INFO  [o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory] Creating Schema History table "public"."flyway_schema_history" ...
13:39:10:410 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.p.Parser] Parsing  ...
13:39:10:421 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.s.ParserSqlScript] Found statement at line 1: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "public"."flyway_schema_history" (
    "installed_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "version" VARCHAR(50),
    "description" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    "type" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    "script" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    "checksum" INT,
    "installed_by" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    "installed_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "execution_time" INT NOT NULL,
    "success" BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "flyway_schema_history_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("installed_rank")
) AS SELECT -1, NULL, '<< Flyway Schema History table created >>', 'TABLE', '', NULL, 'TOOLS', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 0, TRUE
13:39:10:422 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.s.ParserSqlScript] Found statement at line 14: CREATE INDEX "public"."flyway_schema_history_s_idx" ON "public"."flyway_schema_history" ("success")
13:39:10:422 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor] Executing SQL: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "public"."flyway_schema_history" (
    "installed_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "version" VARCHAR(50),
    "description" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    "type" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    "script" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    "checksum" INT,
    "installed_by" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    "installed_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    "execution_time" INT NOT NULL,
    "success" BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "flyway_schema_history_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("installed_rank")
) AS SELECT -1, NULL, '<< Flyway Schema History table created >>', 'TABLE', '', NULL, 'TOOLS', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 0, TRUE
13:39:10:434 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor] 0 rows affected
13:39:10:434 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor] Executing SQL: CREATE INDEX "public"."flyway_schema_history_s_idx" ON "public"."flyway_schema_history" ("success")
13:39:10:437 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.s.DefaultSqlScriptExecutor] 0 rows affected
13:39:10:438 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory] Created Schema History table "public"."flyway_schema_history"
13:39:10:456 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory] Schema History table "public"."flyway_schema_history" successfully updated to reflect changes
13:39:10:482 (main) DEBUG [i.q.f.r.FlywayRecorder] Filtering out resource: db/migration-test/V1.0.0__INITIAL_STRUCTURE_OF_TABLES_WITH_SOME_DATA (filename: V1.0.0__INITIAL_STRUCTURE_OF_TABLES_WITH_SOME_DATA)
13:39:10:482 (main) DEBUG [i.q.f.r.FlywayRecorder] Filtering out resource: db/migration-test/V1.0.0__INITIAL_STRUCTURE_OF_TABLES_WITH_SOME_DATA (filename: V1.0.0__INITIAL_STRUCTURE_OF_TABLES_WITH_SOME_DATA)
13:39:10:492 (main) INFO  [o.f.c.i.c.DbMigrate] Current version of schema "public": null
13:39:10:497 (main) INFO  [o.f.c.i.c.DbMigrate] Schema "public" is up to date. No migration necessary.
13:39:10:498 (main) DEBUG [o.f.c.Flyway] Memory usage: 128 of 305M
13:39:11:910 (main) INFO  [e.c.f.e.Test1Flyway] Starting flyway test
13:39:11:916 (main) ERROR [e.c.f.e.ExampleE] SQL Error: : org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Tabla "T_EXAMPLES" no encontrada
Table "T_EXAMPLES" not found; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO T_EXAMPLES (example_id, description) VALUES (?,?) [42102-200]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:453)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429)
```

My quarkus 1.13.2_Final application.yaml configuration is:

```
"%test":
  quarkus:
    log:
      level: ERROR
      console:
        format: "%d{HH:mm:ss:SSS} (%t) %-5p [%c{1.}] %s%e%n"
        color: true
      category:
        "example.credentials.flyway":
          level: DEBUG
        "org.flywaydb.core":
          level: DEBUG
        "io.quarkus.flyway":
          level: DEBUG
        "org.h2":
          level: DEBUG
    datasource:
      db-kind: h2
      jdbc:
        driver: org.h2.Driver
#        url: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:example;MODE=Oracle
#        url: jdbc:h2:./target/db/example;MODE=Oracle,AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
        url: jdbc:h2:./target/db/example;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
        max-size: 13
    flyway:
      locations: db/migration-test
      clean-at-start: true
      migrate-at-start: true
      schemas: public
```

I will appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your migrations are being ignored by Flyway:

```
[i.q.f.r.FlywayRecorder] Filtering out resource: db/migration-test/V1.0.0__INITIAL_STRUCTURE_OF_TABLES_WITH_SOME_DATA (filename: V1.0.0__INITIAL_STRUCTURE_OF_TABLES_WITH_SOME_DATA)
[i.q.f.r.FlywayRecorder] Filtering out resource: db/migration-test/V1.0.0__INITIAL_STRUCTURE_OF_TABLES_WITH_SOME_DATA (filename: V1.0.0__INITIAL_STRUCTURE_OF_TABLES_WITH_SOME_DATA)
```

It's possible you're missing the `.sql` file extension on your scripts.

Comment: Thanks. It was the reason.